# mongorestore halt at dropping collection

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am restoring mongodb database from a dump by running the following command

```
mongorestore --db=my_db --dir /home/ubuntu/restore/$DUMP/my_db/ --drop --stopOnError --verbose
```

It runs and shows the following line

```
found collection .....
dropping collection .....
```

It stops at this. Can not figure out the problem.

Comment: which version of mongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of using mongorestore.

```
mongorestore --host hostname --port <port number> --db <database_name> -u <username> -p<password> <path_of_backuped_file>
```